# How to get specific element of a String in Java

Tags: java

Am trying to get the 4th element of a string but I keep getting an error saying:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Here is the code:

```
String name = "A";
int number = 6;

String stringToSplit = "Test, " + name + " with " + number + " processes";
String[] split = stringToSplit.split("\\+");
String getNumber = split[4];

Output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You try and split against literal `+` here, and there is none in your input string...

Comment: Use your debugger, or even System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split)), to understand what your split array contains. Then understand why it contains what it contains.

Comment: There are two lines of code to debug, and a very informative error message. Just saying. Don't rush it. And guys, stop spamming identical answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+`  is used to `concatenate` the string literal

You don't have literally `+` in your string try with splitting space `\\s+`

```
String[] split = stringToSplit.split("\\s+");
```

array index start from `0` so get the four index element by `split[3]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java expert, but your code looks like you are trying to split stringToSplit at every "+", but there aren't any "+"es in there. You need to make "+" part of stringToSplit instead of just gluing strings together.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split the string with "+" as separator,but your input string `stringToSplit` does not contain any "+"

Answer (score 0):

For verifying this, you could debug into the code and set a breakpoint on the String array. 
With your split condition you would have no splitting at all (as the other members stated already). 
A look at the split variable at runtime should show you that the array only has a value on index 0 (your whole String) and that the array has size 1.